# What are these notations O(1)/O(n)/O(log n)?

Tags: performance, notation

I am a newbie here I recently read tutorials on java about collection framework. `The time complexity of various objects in reading/writing data` What does it mean? what is `O` notations? can anyone make me understand these notations and about time complexity measures using these notations

Comment: These are known as *asymptotic notation*, and probably explained in your textbook.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Could you spend two minutes of your time in explaining these I read but I could not understand. it would be great help

Comment: See also [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o), …

Comment: This question is too broad. You aren't asking a question about a specific problem here, but looking for a basic presentation of the subjcet. There are already plenty of such presentations on the internet and in textbooks. Please ask here if you have a specific question: some specific part of the explanations that you don't understand, or a specific problem that you face when trying to apply these notions to a particular case.